# Send Email to recipient from MYSQL after the Cronjob run

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I set a cronjob that will run a code every one minute. The objective of this code is to connect to the Mysql and update a certain column to a new value if that value has been in the database for 1 minute. In the parallel, i want to send an email exactly at the same time to the email address exist in the same row. example of the table.

```
| id | title | status | email             |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+
| 1  | title | 1      | email@example.com |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+
| 2  | titl2 | 1      | email1@example.com|
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+
```

And after the cron job runs the table becomes

```
| id | title | status | email             |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+
| 1  | title | 2      | email@example.com |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+
| 2  | titl2 | 2      | email1@example.com|
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+
```

I want at this moment to send an email to the emails where the row status become 2

Here is the code i try.

```
<?php 
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
// Check connection
if ($conn) {

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE jobs SET status = 2 WHERE created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
$em = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM jobs WHERE status = '2' < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");

}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<?
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($em)) {

    $from = 'email@myemail.com';
    $to = $row['email']; // The column where your e-mail was stored.
    $subject = 'Sample Form';
    $msg = 'Hello world!';
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is it `$row_['email']` when it's supposed to be `$row['email']`?

Comment: Sorry that was a small mistake. The code sends email to all email addresses even those changed long time ago. I want the code send email only for new email addresses where the status become 2

Comment: Can't you send an email before changing the status? For example: `SELECT email WHERE status = 1 AND created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)`

Comment: The email should be sent after the status changing. because the email will notify that the post has been disactivated. status = 1 means active. status =2 means disactivated

Comment: I know, what I was saying was you could send an email right before updating the status. But if you want to update the send an email after, then... `SELECT email FROM jobs WHERE status = '2' < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)` should be `SELECT email FROM jobs WHERE status = '2' AND created < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)`, no?

Comment: Still send email to the whole emails out there even those disactivated long time ago, and if the same email exist i multi rows it receives email multiple times as well

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the code above the script but it doesnt show anything. I added what Edward proposed, but the code keeps sending the email to the email address every minute and sends the same email address twice

Comment: Do you have more than one `jobs` row with the same email address in it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, when i echo the $row['email'] it displays all emails where the status =2 . i think i need a code that bring the email or emails of jobs that just disactivated when the cronjob runs. like what Edward proposed but does not work, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. The code used to get all emails even those have status = 2 long time ago.

```
<?php 
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
// Check connection
if ($conn) {

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE jobs SET status = 2 WHERE created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
    $em = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email, title FROM jobs WHERE status = 2 AND created BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)) AND NOW()");
}
mysqli_close($conn);?>
<?
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($em)) {

$from = 'email@myemail.com';
$to = $row['email']; // The column where your e-mail was stored.
$subject = 'Sample Form';
$msg = 'Hello world!';
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
}
?>
```